# openstack masakari, AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'instance_ha'

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I want to make instance HA for my Openstack instance with `Masakari` project which I installed `masakari-api` and `masakari-engine` on Controller nodes and `masakari-processmonitor`, `masakari-instancemonitor` and `masakari-hostmonitor` on Compute nodes but when I am going to test failed `openstack-nova-compte` service to test instance HA I get this error:

```
2019-02-02T10:10:03.782541+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: Command: systemctl restart openstack-nova-compute.service
2019-02-02T10:10:03.782972+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: Exit code: 1
2019-02-02T10:10:03.783363+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: Stdout: u''
2019-02-02T10:10:03.783785+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: Stderr: u'Job for openstack-nova-compute.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status openstack-nova-compute.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.\n': ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
2019-02-02T10:10:08.776654+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.775 115036 INFO masakarimonitors.ha.masakari [-] **Send a notification**. {'notification': {'hostname': '<my_domain_name>', 'type': 'PROCESS', 'payload': {'process_name': '/usr/bin/nova-compute', 'event': 'STOPPED'}, 'generated_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 2, 6, 40, 8, 774997)}}
2019-02-02T10:10:08.780948+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process [-] Exception caught: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'instance_ha': AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'instance_ha'
2019-02-02T10:10:08.781513+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-02T10:10:08.782106+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/masakarimonitors/processmonitor/process.py", line 75, in main
2019-02-02T10:10:08.782882+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process     self.process_handler.restart_processes(down_process_list)
2019-02-02T10:10:08.783546+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/masakarimonitors/processmonitor/process_handler/handle_process.py", line 203, in restart_processes
2019-02-02T10:10:08.784149+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process     event)
2019-02-02T10:10:08.784772+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/masakarimonitors/ha/masakari.py", line 60, in send_notification
2019-02-02T10:10:08.785349+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process     client = self._make_client()
2019-02-02T10:10:08.785902+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/masakarimonitors/ha/masakari.py", line 43, in _make_client
2019-02-02T10:10:08.786500+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process     return conn.instance_ha
2019-02-02T10:10:08.786998+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'instance_ha'
2019-02-02T10:10:08.787561+03:30 c2 masakari-processmonitor: 2019-02-02 10:10:08.778 115036 ERROR masakarimonitors.processmonitor.process
```

- I check my connection to controller nodes and compute node, all of them is OK.
- I check the Rabbitmq queues and it has masakari ha-engine queue.
- I check the MySQL for masakari database and I have that too.

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES FROM  masakari;

failover_segments

hosts

migrate_version

notifications
```

Every thing looks correct but where is my problem, do I miss some things.

Answer (score -2):

The problem seems like

> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'instance_ha'.

In stable/queens, this issue is fixed with [this patch](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/588157/).

If you still find this issue in stable/queens or any other version,
I recommend you to file a bug report to OpenStack masakari-monitors via [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/masakari-monitors). Please include the OpenStack version details.